# Getting selected option on edit form in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

i want to edit user profile which has a country, country field is a select option, i want to get a user's country value in select field, i tried the answer in stack but it didn't work for me knowing there is relationship between user and country belongsTo hasMany.

**edit.blade.php**

```
<select id="country" name="country_id" class="form-control" >
                                      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
                                      @foreach($countries as $country)
                                      <option value="{{$country->id}} {{ $country->id == $users->country_id ? 'selected' : '' }}"> {{ $country->name }}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                 </select>
```

**usersController.php**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $users     = Auth::user();
        $countries = Country::all();

        return view('users.edit')->with([
            'users'     => $users,
            'countries' => $countries
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: does the user have a `country_id` set currently?

Comment: @lagbox thx its work i remove <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

`<option value="{{$country->id}} {{ $country->id == $users->country_id ? 'selected' : '' }}"> {{ $country->name }}</option>`

I believe you want this:

`<option value="{{$country->id}}"{{ $country->id == $users->country_id ? ' selected' : '' }}> {{ $country->name }}</option>`

Comment: I think you're correct, but questions that are the result of a typographic error are not on topic. Instead of answering, flag them for closure.